# #1241 - Operando debe tener 1 columna(s) en una subconsulta

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, subconsultas

Me permito editar mi pregunta.

Estas son las 3 tablas con las cuales estoy trabajando:

[image: tabla reserva]

[image: tabla clientes]

[image: tabla pais]

con estas tablas debo resolver esta consulta que dice asi:

•   Muestra todos los datos de los clientes españoles que hayan reservado un vehículo más de una vez.

para resolver esta incognita, utilice la siguiente consulta
lo estoy intentando consultar de la siguiente forma:

[image: consulta realizada]

y al darle continuar me esta arrojando el siguiente error.

[image: Error que me da phpMyAdmin]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Para entender que tratas de hacer.. que quisiste hacer con esto?and 
 (SELECT *
 FROM clientes
     WHERE clientes.idPais = 1
 )

Comment: pon la estructura de tus tablas

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene la sub-consulta del `and`? Poniendo el criterio así bastaría: `WHERE reservas.idCliente = clientes.idCliente and clientes.idPais = 1` si lo que quieres es filtar por el país con id igual a `1`. Si es otra cosa lo que quieres, pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta, explicando el sentido de esa sub-consulta que está fallando.

Comment: Adjunto toda la información necesaria haber si puedo salir de este atasco,

Comment: tu consulta esta mal escrita y no tiene sentido (como te pregunte en mi primer comentario).. no podes poner and (consulta).. que esperas que haga eso?

Comment: Las consultas y los datos de ejemplo deben ir _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Aparte, como te preguntaron anteriormente: ¿qué es lo que estás buscando hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sustituyendo el `*` por `idCliente` y añadiendo `idCliente` justo después del `AND` ya casi lo tendrías a falta de combinarlo con la tabla de clientes para obtener todos los datos de esos registros. La consulta completa podría quedar más o menos así tras optimizarla un poco:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes
  WHERE idPais=(
    SELECT idPais FROM paises
      WHERE nom_pais='España'
  ) AND idCliente IN (
    SELECT idCliente
      FROM reservas
      GROUP BY 1
      HAVING COUNT(*)>1  
  );
```

Procura realizar los agrupamientos y totales con la menor cantidad de datos, dejando las combinaciones con otras tablas para el final:

```
SELECT idCliente
  FROM reservas
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios a esta respuesta e intenta seguir las recomendaciones que te han dejado en los comentarios a tu pregunta para que podamos responderte más rápido en el futuro.

Comment: Gracias David por tu respuesta, me ayudo mucho para solucionar  este ejercicio y otros dos mas que tenia

Comment: Estupendo, esa es la idea. Esperamos verte más por aquí.